# TableView not displaying all the columns using scrollbar

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I am using a TableView and adding the columns dynamically.  The column headers are nested where there is a Week header with the individual days for that week nested under week header.

```
        TableColumn<EmployeeForWeeksDbm, String> week2fx = new TableColumn<>("Week " + (weekNum ));
        week2fx.setSortable(false);

        TableColumn<EmployeeForWeeksDbm, String> day21fx = new TableColumn<>(dateHeader(ld));
        day21fx.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().d8Property());
        day21fx.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(ltList));
        day21fx.setSortable(false);

        ldAdjust = ld.plusDays(1);
        TableColumn<EmployeeForWeeksDbm, String> day22fx = new TableColumn<>(dateHeader(ldAdjust));
        day22fx.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().d9Property());
        day22fx.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(ltList));
        day22fx.setSortable(false);
```

I then add the days into the week header;

```
week2fx.getColumns().addAll(day21fx,day22fx,day23fx,day24fx,day25fx,day26fx,day27fx);
```

Since i have 4 weeks that i wish to display;

```
mainscheduleTVfx.getColumns().addAll(employeefx,week1fx,week2fx,week3fx,week4fx);
```

Every thing is added correctly and it appears as intended. The data loads, comboboxes work and everything is great !  However, when the window is reduced in size the scroll bars are engaged (using default TableView scrollbars) and when we scroll to the furthest right, the last column seems to be clipped.

[this image shows the right edge of the TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQUqc.jpg)

At first i thought i had used Scenebuilder incorrectly but i can only just have the TableView and nothing else and it still clips the end

Here is the code for the scene;

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorpanefx" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller_SchedMan">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="mainscheduleTVfx" layoutX="184.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the code for the Header title, incase you are wondering;

```
 private String dateHeader(LocalDate ld) {
        String dayHeader = ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd"));
        return dayHeader;
    }
```

It does not seem to matter what i do, i get the clipping at the end. I think it is how i create and add my columns but i am not sure where i am going wrong.  Again everything else work perfectly, except for the last column clipping.  I also noticed that if i do not add as many "weeks" the clipping is reduced. Well it seems that way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that by setting a max width, i was able to eliminate the clipping.

day21fx.setMaxWidth(60);//clipping for the day

I also had to make sure that the maximum was set for the up stream header;
week2fx.setMaxWidth(60*7);

Despite having fixed the problem, i do not quite understand why TableView would clip in the first place. More reading i supppose.